# association window <-> .desktop file <-> launcher entry

Tags: unity, launcher, .desktop, ayatana

I'm trying to integrate my JS code with unity using low level dbus messaging. I'm able to set launcher icon properties (progress, count, menu etc) for known .desktop files ( for example, "gnome-terminal.desktop" ) Also, I can create my own .desktop file, but it's only visible in launcher if I drag & drop it from /usr/share/applications onto launcher. If I just click on .desktop file, new window causes opening new entry on launcher not associated with that .desktop file. I think I'm missing some step where I tell some service ( Registrar? ) that the window I created is part of my .desktop

script started by clicking on desktop icon (no .desktop icon in launcher menu, "unknown icon" window icon for new window:
[image: screen shot 2014-09-30 at 12 36 50 pm]

Drag & drop .desktop file to launcher. Now have two icons, and results of LauncherEntry progress updates visible on the first one.
[image: screen shot 2014-09-30 at 12 37 51 pm]

So the question is "how do I tell unity that my window belongs to that .desktop file"

my script and .desktop file: https://gist.github.com/sidorares/8d0587e384176f1be83d (I'm using [node-x11](https://github.com/sidorares/node-x11), [node-dbus](https://github.com/sidorares/node-dbus) and [node-dbusmenu](https://github.com/sidorares/node-dbusmenu))

Comment: Please paste the content of the `.desktop` file

Comment: I modified update-manager file, here is content: https://gist.github.com/sidorares/8d0587e384176f1be83d (added link to post)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found answer by looking at [bamf source](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~unity-team/bamf/trunk/view/head:/src/bamf-matcher.c#L1632) - you need to set `_NET_WM_DESKTOP_FILE` property to be full path to desktop file.

Comment: Thanks Andrey very much for this question and solution. So if I change the desktop file to be full path, then it will change the icon in the launcher right away? And will _NET_WM_ICON propery have to be set to change the icon in the alt+tab panel?

Comment: Hi @AndreySidorov I have a desktop.file that launches a window. The iconpath is a name in the themes i added, its name is "profilist_beta". I overwrite the icons in the `/home/noit/share/icons/hicons/##_##/apps/profilist_beta.png` and then the desktop file on the desktop refreshes the icon, however the alt+tab and unity bar dont take the menu. Will this solution you shared, of setting the `_NET_WM_DESKTOP_FILE` to the path of the desktop file make the windows take?

Comment: here is a screencast of my dilemma. It also shows a smaller issue in that the desktop file icon does not update till I click/select the icon. [Youtube :: Delay Dynamically Updating Desktop File and Dependents](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QUIBoaofopU)

Comment: For the issue where the icon doesnt update of the desktop file till you click the desktop file or select it. I found clicking on a file epxlorer window also updates the desktop file icon. Just wanted to let you know in case it would give you better understandng :)

Comment: Hi Andrey, I have Firefox open and its windows are attached to unity launcher. I want to change that icon.So i was thinking of adding a new launcher to the unity bar and then detach firefox windows from that .desktop launcher and connect it to my newly added .desktop launcher, is this possible? Thanks :)

Comment: don't know :) try and see

Comment: Aw haha ok thanks man would you be able to chat i get really into the x11 mode when working with you :D I can share with you copy paste jsctypes from firefox. you showed me node=x11 i find it only fair i show off fiefox jsctypes now :D

Comment: Hey man what X function would i use to set `_NET_WM_DESKTOP_FILE`, I'm doing `XChangeProperty` on the window right now that sounds right right?

Comment: Hey @Noitidart ping me at https://gitter.im/sidorares/node-x11

Comment: Hi Andrey I just tried it. I 3 windows associated with blue firefox icon and then 3 with beta firefox icon. I'm trying to move one window from blue firefox icon to beta icon. I do `XGetWindowProperty` to show that `_NET_WM_DESKTOP_FILE` is before and after I change it. The change is successful however the window does not move from the blue icon to the beta icon :( Here's a video showing it: [Youtube :: Changing _NET_WM_DESKTOP_FILE of Window but Window Won't Move](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ygas9qaxDc0)